# Таблица сделала переход на следующую строку, хотя делать этого она не должна была. Что делать?

Tags: html, html5

Начал изучать Html недавно. Задача была сделать таблицу. Но в какой-то момент она перешла на следующую строку.

[image: Это и есть сама таблица]

Вот код, по которому строится таблица.

```html
<table border=1>
            <caption>Дни с ясной и дождливой погодой в месяц (суммарно по часам)</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Месяц</th><th>Янв.</th><th>Фев.</th><th>Март</th>
                    <th>Апр.</tr><th>Май</th><th>Июнь</th><th>Июль</th>     <th>Авг</th><th>Сен</th>
                    <th>Окт</th><th>Ноя</th><th>Дек</th><th>Год</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Солнечное сияние, день</b></td>
                    <td>10</td><td>10</td><td>9</td>
                    <td>8</tr><td>8</td><td>8</td>
                    <td>10</td><td>9</td><td>7</td>
                    <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>106</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Дождь, день</b></td>
                    <td>14</td><td>12</td><td>12</td>
                    <td>10</tr><td>10</td><td>14</td>
                    <td>13</td><td>12</td><td>10</td>
                    <td>9</td><td>10</td><td>12</td><td>136</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Не совсем понимаю, что произошло. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внимательно смотри на закрывающие тэги: там иногда `/tr` вместо `/th` или `/td`.